# Value of expression $\frac{1}{1+z^{8k}+z^{16k}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $z$ is a complex number such that $z^{23}=1.$ Then $\displaystyle \sum^{22}_{k=1}\frac{1}{1+z^{8k}+z^{16k}}$

What I try : Using

$z^{23}=1\Longrightarrow z^{24}=z\Longrightarrow z^{24k}=z^k$

So $\displaystyle \sum^{22}_{k=1}\frac{z^{8k}-1}{(1+z^{8k}+z^{16k})\cdot (z^{8k}-1)}$

$\displaystyle =\sum^{22}_{k=1}\frac{z^{8k}-1}{z^{24k}-1}$

$\displaystyle =\sum^{22}_{k=1}\frac{z^{8k}-1}{z^k-1}$

$\displaystyle =\sum^{22}_{k=1}\bigg(1+z^{k}+z^{2k}+\cdots +z^{7k}\bigg)$

I did not understand How I solve it because when  Directly calculate each term with summation is very Complex

Please have a look on that Problem, Thanks

Comment: Check this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/971846/42969, the same approach works here.

Comment: For integer $a \not\equiv 0\pmod {23}$, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{22} z^{ak} = \frac{z^a - z^{23a}}{1 - z^a} = \frac{z^a - 1}{1-z^a} = -1$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the value of $\sum_{m=1}^{19} \frac{1}{\zeta^{3m}+\zeta^{2m}+\zeta^{m}+1}$ with $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/19}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971757/what-is-the-value-of-sum-m-119-frac1-zeta3m-zeta2m-zetam1) – It is the same problem only with different numbers, and the solution method is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Going on from where you stopped, one has :
$$
\begin{align}
\sum^{22}_{k=1} \left(1+z^{k}+z^{2k}+\cdots +z^{7k}\right) 
   &= 22 + \sum_{n=1}^7 \sum^{22}_{k=1} z^{nk} \\
   &= 22 + \sum_{n=1}^7 \sum^{22}_{k=1} \left(\frac{z^{23n}-1}{z^n-1}-1\right) \\
   &= 22 + \sum_{n=1}^7 (-1) \\
   &= 15
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You're right, my bad; I didn't notice that the case $n = 0$ doesn't represent a geometric sequence at first glance. Now it is corrected.